# Why won't this ... if .Document.getElementById("") = "" then ... work?

Tags: vbscript, getelementbyid

Here's basically what I'm trying to do, I'm just trying to make a alert if a user on that site creates an item/image it alerts me with a message.

So I'm grabbing the elements but seems like it's not working any help?

```
Id=114613970
Do
  WScript.Sleep 1100
  frame.Visible = True
  frame.Navigate ("http://www.roblox.com/Item.aspx?ID=" & Id)
  WScript.Sleep 100
  set item = frame.Document.getElementByID("ctl00_cphRoblox_CreatorHyperLink")
  if frame.Document.getElementByID("ctl00_cphRoblox_CreatorHyperLink") = "<a    id='ctl00_cphRoblox_CreatorHyperLink' class='stat notranslate' href='User.aspx?ID=10744036'>"  & thexmarcoxz & "</a>" Then
    WScript.Echo "ROBLOX: ASSET DECAL"
  End if
  Id = Id + 1
Loop
```

I'm still new to this but thanks!

Comment: Is your question about VBScript or VBA? They are not the same language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementById()` returns an object (the selected node from the DOM tree). While this object represents the HTML tag, it's not the same as a string with the HTML tag. However, you can retrieve that string via the object's `outerHtml` property. Try this:

```
set item = frame.Document.getElementByID("ctl00_cphRoblox_CreatorHyperLink")
if item.outerHtml = "<a    id='ctl00_cphRoblox_CreatorHyperLink' class='stat notranslate' href='User.aspx?ID=10744036'>" & thexmarcoxz & "</a>" Then
  WScript.Echo "ROBLOX: ASSET DECAL"
End if
```

Another issue is that your loop is infinite, i.e. it doesn't have a terminating condition that will cause the loop to end at some point. Because of that it will continue incrementing `Id` endlessly. If you want the loop to terminate when the first match is found you need to do something like this:

```
Id=114613970
Do
  WScript.Sleep 1100
  frame.Visible = True
  frame.Navigate ("http://www.roblox.com/Item.aspx?ID=" & Id)
  WScript.Sleep 100
  set item = frame.Document.getElementByID("ctl00_cphRoblox_CreatorHyperLink")
  Id = Id + 1
Loop Until item.outerHtml = "<a    id='ctl00_cphRoblox_CreatorHyperLink' class='stat notranslate' href='User.aspx?ID=10744036'>" & thexmarcoxz & "</a>"
WScript.Echo "ROBLOX: ASSET DECAL"
```

Another thing I just noticed, `navigate` runs asynchronously, so you have to wait for the operation to finish:

```
frame.Navigate ("http://www.roblox.com/Item.aspx?ID=" & Id)
While frame.Busy : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! but sadly still isn't working =/ properly

Comment: Alright, so the webpage is navigating to webpages, and does a loop and adds on +1 on the Id=(some number) and goes and on keeps on adding. after it finds a certain asset I want to alert me =P

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, but sadly for some odd reason when the VBScript runs the message box pops ups which makes it stop right when I turn it on

Comment: The loop terminates once it finds a matching tag. Is that not what you want? If so, please update your question with a more detailed description of what you want the script to do.

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted I just got confused, sorry about that. it runs smoothly but when I open it, it does run but it just stops after the first search (+1) and when I check who created it its not the user I was looking for. I just want it to scan for an item (from a certain user) but the problem is after I open it it just stops right after I click it, and its not the user im looking for.

Comment: If you need the ID that was used in the last request after the loop finishes, you need to increment `Id` before calling `frame.navigate`. Also, what is your actual stop condition? Like I said before, please update your question with a more detailed description of what the script should do.

Comment: Alright I moved the increment Id before the frame.navigate, and it just stops like right after I open it scans just ONCE +1 then just stops and gives me the WScript.Echo "Finished" I'm looking into why its doing that right now

Answer (score 0):

Not positive, but "Document" is usually lower case: document.getElementById
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById

Comment: can you print out the value of 'item'?

Comment: <div id="assetContainer">
<div id="Thumbnail">
<a id="ctl00_cphRoblox_AssetThumbnailImage" disabled="disabled" class="AssetThumbnailImage" title="bluesteel" onclick="return false" style="display:inline-block;height:320px;width:320px;"><img src="http://t1ak.roblox.com/4609601e4db90bfcfba9de29042fa3c4" height="320" width="320" border="0" onerror="return Roblox.Controls.Image.OnError(this)" alt="bluesteel"></a>    
                            </div>
                        </div>

Comment: why is it pulling in two containing divs? It getElementByID should only return the A tag, not it's parents????

Comment: DeweyOx, sorry I'm still very new to this. I hardly know what a parent is. lol